# Host a mySQL Server

Tags: mysql, localhost, hosting

I am making a Javafx program and need to use a small mySQL database. Currently I am hosting one on my computer but I can't access it on other computers on other networks. I need the mySQL server to be accessible from anywhere. How do I host one that does that? Thanks in advance, all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a few options depending on how important this MySQL database is to you, how you intend to connect to it from outside, and what you want to do with it.

1. The naive implementation would involve opening your firewall and directing all incoming traffic using whatever port you have configured MySQL for to point to the ip address of your server.  If you do this **you absolutely must secure your database with a password!!!**  You'll also need to keep the server's public ip address handy so you know how to find it when you go out.
2. Use Amazon AWS, Google Compute, Google App Engine, or some other cloud platform to host a MySQL instance.  All the big players also tend to host pretty awesome RDBMS solutions.  The advantage here is that you're not exposing your home computer to malice and you are connecting into an ecosystem that will answer a lot of other questions for you as they come up along the way (IE - how do you ensure redundancy?  Backups?  Scale your network for traffic?).  There's a ton of other advantages too.  It's the cloud... dude...
3. Use a SaaS DB service such as Firebase (*Note: We are leaving MySQL and SQL database territory with Firebase*)

If you plan to let other parties access your MySQL instance to make use of your data, you might also want to consider implementing a REST API (or SOAP API if you hate the future) which acts as an abstraction layer to interact with and provide the data from your database in a consistent and reliable format.

Best answer I can give with the details afforded - look around though the options in this arena are near limitless depending on how and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think I am going to use my public one. Its literally for like a few days and its going to be small. Could you send me a link or something of how I would do #1. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Default port is 3306 (I would change it, quick and dirty safety improvement - just remember obscurity is not really security).  Beyond that a generic "port forward <your home router type>" should fill in the rest.  Every router differs some, but the key is "port forwarding".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your machine from your LAN pretty easily unless there is some firewall rules preventing opening connection to your machine. Another way is there are many cloud shosting providers has free tier you can signup to bring up a test instance of mysql. Example: [Open Shift](https://www.openshift.com/).